# MySQL query to return only 3 matching rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that stores configuration options.

config_options table as follows

```
------------------------------------------------
id    config_id     q_id    ans_id
------------------------------------------------
1       5            602      152
2       5            603      156
3       6            610      169
4       6            603      156
5       6            602      152
6       28           603      157
7       28           601      107
```

For example if a user selects question and option 602->152, 603->156, 610->169
I am expecting result should show only 3 rows (3,4,5).

I am getting this result:

```
------------------------------
id  config_id   q_id    ans_id
------------------------------
1   5           603     156
2   5           602     152
3   6           610     169
4   6           603     156
5   6           602     152
```

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM config_options a
WHERE (a.q_id=602 and a.ans_id=152) OR
      (a.q_id=610 and a.ans_id=169) OR
      (a.q_id=603 and a.ans_id=156)
ORDER BY config_id
```

Here is the path to SQLFIDDLE
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c73a1

```
CREATE TABLE config_options (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
config_id int,
  q_id int,
  ans_id int
);
INSERT INTO config_options
  (config_id,q_id,ans_id)
VALUES
  (5,603,156),
  (5,602,152),
  (6,610,169),
  (6,603,156),
  (6,602,152),
  (28,603,157),
  (28,601,107);
```

Comment: Rows with `id` 1 and 2 also match, but by which logic are they being excluded?

Comment: For example if one user selects question and option 602->152, 603->156, 610->169 I am expecting result should show only 3 rows(3,4,5). This is my logic. I know my query is wrong. I need some help achieve my logic.

Comment: You still haven't told us what your logic is, and youe query is _right_ insofar that it does select those questions and answers.

Comment: Read for example paragraph

Comment: There are _two_ records in your sample data which have `602 -> 152`, hence your current query would return _two_ records for this pair.  But you expect only one record, hence I keep asking you questions though am not getting any help.

Comment: I need 3 rows as 3 conditions matched

Comment: So ANY three rows where the conditions matched?

Answer (score 1):

This is your result set:

```
------------------------------
id  config_id   q_id    ans_id
------------------------------
1   5           603     156
2   5           602     152
3   6           610     169
4   6           603     156
5   6           602     152
```

Any three rows from this result set would satisfy your current criteria. So `ORDER BY id RAND() LIMIT 3` is a valid answer - unless, as I (and others) suspect, you haven't articulated the problem properly.

Comment: @halfer Which badge are you going after? ;-)

Comment: Heh, not really a badge person - just a compulsive tidier `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

it will work for you as per your concern

```
SELECT max(id)as id,config_id,q_id,ans_id
FROM config_options a
WHERE (a.q_id=602 and a.ans_id=152) OR
      (a.q_id=610 and a.ans_id=169) OR
      (a.q_id=603 and a.ans_id=156)
group by ans_id
ORDER BY id asc
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c73a1/15/%20''sqlfiddle%22)